Can identical isothermal operations result in opposite free energy changes for different systems?
Background:
I am considering the conditions under which an intelligent choice of operations fundamentally impacts the amount of work extracted. To explore this, it seems helpful to investigate the following question, as it may help clarify the conditions under which the same operation proves to be effective.
Setting of Initial State:
Consider two thermodynamic systems, S1 and S2, each consisting of a real gas enclosed in a separate container. These systems are independently operated on and share the following properties:

Both are in equilibrium with the same heat bath at the initial state.
The entropies of S1 and S2 takes maximum value with respect to the position of internal constraints (if present).
The size and shape of containers are identical at the initial state.
Containers may be flexible (it can be expanded or compressed)
Gases may have different compositions.

Operation:
Suppose we perform the identical reversible operation on both systems. This operation could involve manipulating the container or applying external forces but does not involve mixing any other substance with S1 or S2. Let us denote the extracted work from S1 and S2 by $W_1$ an $W_2$, respectively.
Main Question:
Is it possible for this (same) operation to increase the Helmholtz free energy of S1 (requiring work input) while decreasing it for S2 (allowing work extraction)?
Sub-questions:

If the answer is yes, what differences between S1 and S2 essentially lead to $W_1 W_2 < 0$?
Does this phenomenon extend to non-gaseous thermodynamic systems?

Additional note:

The second condition in the “Setting of Initial State” section was added to exclude trivial cases, as illustrated in Figure 1. In this model, a movable partition, which works as an internal constraint prohibited by the second condition, is placed in the center of the rectangular container. The gas particles in S2 are positioned on the side opposite to those in S1, so moving the partition in the same direction would result in work with opposite signs.
I excluded the mixing of substances because if insert a material that strongly reacts with S1 but not S2, S2 is compressed, resulting in a higher free energy, but S1 settles into a lower energy state, more than offsetting the compression. (Chemomechanics suggested this example in my previous question.)


Figure 1: In S1, a black dot (representing a gas particle) is on one side of a movable partition, and in S2, a white circle (representing another gas particle) is on the opposite side. By performing the same operation (i.e., moving the partition in the same direction), the work extracted from S1 is positive, while it is negative for S2: $W_1 > 0,\ W_2 < 0$.

Previous question (not necessarily universally visible), for context.

I do not understand what you are asking: Taking $dF=-SdT-\delta W$ with work $\delta W =pdV$ and if isothermal $dT=0$ and getting the same  volume displacement $dV$ with the same pressure $p$ why would $dF$ be different? What am I missing here?

@hyportnex If the only operation allowed is to change the shape of the container, then your argument is clearly correct. What I want to know is the more general case. That is, (1) Does $W_1W_2 >0$ hold for any operation allowed by the laws of physics (except mixing with other substances)? (2) What about in non-gaseous thermodynamic systems?

Equilibrium with a thermal bath and maximum entropy seem like incoherent assumptions. The maximum entropy holds for isolated systems.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 In the system S2 in Figure 1, the only internal constraint is the operating partition. Let $\lambda$ be its position in the horizontal direction. The entropy of S2 with respect to the internal constraint can then be written as $S(\lambda)$, where $S(\lambda)$ is maximum when $\lambda=0$ (that is, when the partition is at the left end). This is often discussed in the context of the Szilard engine.

If the whole system is isolated, the maxent principle is correct. If the global system exchanges energy with a thermostat, the correct variational principle is the minimum of the Helmholtz free energy. This is a basic  concept in Thermodynamics, independent of the particular system.

If other operations and interactions are also allowed than only pressure-volume then between two equilibrium states characterized by $x_k$ and $y_k$ conjugate extensive and intensive variables the work by the system is $$\delta W=y_1dx_1+y_2dx_2+...+y_ndx_n \tag{1}$$ with its free energy change $$dF=-SdT-\delta W \tag{2}.$$
If for two isothermal cases $\delta W^1=\delta W^2$ where $\delta W^j=\sum_ky_k^jdx_k^j;j=1,2$ then per force $dF^1=dF^2.$
It can happen though that certain extensive variables are internal (also called hidden or concealed) in the sense that either they are not controlled intentionally or unintentionally because we do not even know they exist, or just by their very nature are impossible to be controlled by an external intensive reservoir. For example, the gas molecules may have electric dipole moments and the pressure is high enough, the molecules close enough so that they do also interact electrostatically. An external electrostatic field may control their interaction somewhat but we choose not do so, or they are uncontrollable because of the complexity of their shape; another example for a measurable internal variable would be diffusion within a solid. Here is a quote form Bridgman:

We now turn to the consideration of an entirely
different sort of irreversible process within solids, such
as is met with in changes from order to disorder.
A typical example would be a binary alloy, in which
the atoms of the two elements may be either arranged
regularly on the space lattice, each element being confined
to one sort of site, or else in which the two elements
may occupy either sort of site at random. We
suppose that the degree of internal disorder may be
specified by a parameter $\alpha$ in addition to the ordinary
pressure $(p)$ and temperature $(T)$ which we will suppose necessary for the description of this system. The parameter
$\alpha$ is not directly connected to any additional
external force variable, so that we cannot directly alter
$\alpha$ as we wish by appropriate external manipulation.
It is, however, a property of the system that at any
temperature and pressure the system slowly assumes an
equilibrium condition with the appropriate value of $\alpha$.
If pressure and temperature of the system are rapidly
changed, $\alpha$ does not change and ordinary reversible
thermodynamics applies. If, on the other hand, pressure
and temperature are changed infinitely slowly, the
system is always in equilibrium, with equilibrium values
of $\alpha$, and again reversible thermodynamics applies, but
naturally with different values for the physical constants
of the system. By combining rapid changes with
waiting until equilibrium has completely or partially reestablished
itself, we obviously acquire control over the
variable $\alpha$ within the limits set by its equilibrium values.
What the values are at any stage of the process we
suppose ascertainable by some process, such as x-ray
analysis, which has no thermodynamic coupling, so
that the parameter $\alpha$ has an "operational" significance.

What is important to note here is that one can have internal observable dissipative processes that generate entropy and thus inherently irreversible irrespective of how the external controls applied.
If you have these internal variables present then there is no guarantee that an isothermal process starting and ending with the same free energies would be performed with the same work. The isothermal external work does not describe the free energy change that will also depend on the variation of the system's internal variables.
It is usually stated that Eq (1) and (2) to hold is sufficient that the two equilibrium states be infinitesimally close to each other and how one is reached from the other is irrelevant. To state this it is assumed tacitly that in Eq (1) we have listed all the possible energetic interactions the body may experience. But if some interactions are not listed then $dF, \delta W$ will be process dependent because of the ensuing internal dissipation, ie., "friction", represented by the unobserved or uncontrolled internal variables.
[1] Bridgman: "The Thermodynamics of Plastic Deformation and Generalized Entropy, " Rev. Mod. Phys. 1950,
[2] Finck: THERMODYNAMICS: FROM THE CLASSIC AND GENERALIZED STANDPOINTS, 1955, Bookman Associates, New York

I may have misunderstood due to my lack of ability, but I understand the main point of your response is that even if $\delta W^1=\delta W^2$, $dF^1≠dF^2$ may be true due to dissipation caused by changes in internal variables. Is my understanding correct? Also, I don't understand how this fact relates to what I want to know (i.e., whether $W_1W_2<0$ for the same operation). If there is something I am missing, I would appreciate it if you could point it out to me.

Yes, that is what I meant. My point was that in an irreversible process, be it isothermal or otherwise, there is no direct relationship between $dF$ an d$\delta W$ therefore you can have $dF^1=dF^2$ and $\delta W^1\ne \delta W^2$ even of the opposite signs. Note that just saying that you do same operation is not enough if the process is irreversible because of the internal, hidden variables causing the irreversibility.

You can restore the state from a starting point defined by active and nonactive macroscopic observables, see the hysteresis of a ferromagnet but you cannot control the internal variables, specifically the domain boundaries individually in detail as the magnet goes through the B-H curve. Another example would be plastic deformation where internal dislocations are the cause of plastic flow and the source of the stress-strain hysteresis. If you start with the same domain structure or with the same dislocations in two different specimen then the same process will be repeated in detail, too.
